# Is there a way to start wsl2 (vmmen) only if I need it?

Tags: linux, docker, autostart, wsl-2

I wanted to try out different programs via dockers hub. Therefore I installed wsl2. Wsl2 needs a lot of RAM. I wanted to ask if there is a way to start wsl2 (vmmen) only when I need it?

Comment: sorry if I'm wrong, but doesn't wsl only start when you choose to start it?

Comment: @21rw Every time I start windows I have to stutdown wsl manually. Because it starts automatically.But somehow I did not come up with the very simple and logical solution to simply disable the program in the autostart

Comment: Did you find the answer?